# How do I remove notifications from certain websites not in my Chrome or Safari browsers?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, notifications

I am getting notifications from sites I have visited in the past such as SitePoint. I have gone to the Chrome extensions and I do not see it there and I checked out my MacBook notifications, nothing there regarding these sites and yes I have also checked out the Internet Accounts, nothing there either.

How do I stop receiving those annoying notifications from these vendors?

I don't mind the alerts, I just want to end them for some particular vendors.

Comment: Your Mac may have been infected be experiencing Malware and Adware. Download the free version of [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.com/mac/) and scan your Mac ASAP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome notification settings are at **Preferences > Advanced > Privacy and security > Content settings > Notifications**:

The notifications with jigsaw piece icons next to them are set via their corresponding Chrome extension. Those with three vertical dots next to them can be blocked/allowed, edited or removed.

[image: ChromeNotificationSettings]

The Safari notification settings, which should be self-explanatory, are at **Preferences > Websites > Notifications**:

[image: SafariNotificationSettings]

Answer (score 0):

Go to safari preferences and then in websites tab. Second last in the list is notifications. Edit whichever you want.

Might have similar for chrome. I don’t use it so don’t know.

In Firefox, searching settings for permissions gives me the option.