# Can't disable desktop notifications for a single site in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, notifications

A while ago, I accidentally allowed WhatsApp Web (web.whatsapp.com) to send desktop notifications. I tried to revoke that permission via the Preferences (as also described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/346054/121968)):

[image]

but to no avail:

[image]

What can I do, other than disabling notifications for Safari in the *System* Preferences, which I don't want (I have other websites I might need them for)?

This happens on a 2020 MacBook Pro (M1, 13") running macOS 12.3.1, and Safari 15.4

Comment: Can you just select on the "web.whatsapp.com" line and click the `remove` button below?

Comment: @AVelj yes - not sure how I missed that, I guess it's less discoverable than the dropdown and it ... doesn't really make sense to have two of these similar options? Thanks anyway!

Comment: no stress! I'm not sure why it kept sending you notifications when you disabled it in Safari's website settings, but all I can think of is that you didn't restart Safari/macOS after disabling notifications for the website, or the relevant plist file hadn't been recompiled after you changed the notification setting for the website at the time. I can't seem to find the relevant plist file on my end (probably because I have not allowed notifications for individual websites), but I suspect that's where it probably went wrong. It's a simple fix generally with erroneous plist files :)

Comment: P.S. If you found my original comment above useful, you can upvote it, which gives me some brownie points. I hope you have a great day! :)

Comment: @AVelj I can upvote your comment, but that doesn't give reputation points (it only helps for the [Pundit badge](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/24/pundit)). I can't accept my own answer yet; because it's a self-answer, that can only be done 48 hours after posting the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As user @AVelj mentioned, it's possible to *select* the row and click the Remove button at the bottom:

[image]

That did the trick: when I reload the page, I see a reminder of WhatsApp to enable notifications, which is as expected:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement. You should mark your question as answered now :)